# Добавить в решение другой проект из контроля версий

Tags: visual-studio, git, svn

Допустим, есть какое-то решение, которое добавлено в SVN, в котором я собственно сейчас работаю.

Можно ли из SVN добавить в текущее решение проект из другого решения, что бы внося изменения в этот импортированный проект(например, библиотека), они так же  комитились в своем первоначальном решении?

В интерфейсе, я что-то ничего похоже на то, что мне нужно, не нашел...

Может быть другие программы контроля версий это умеют делать?

**P.S** Честно, мало работал с контролем версий и может быть мой подход неправильный и это делается как-то по другому.

Comment: Убрал метки, т.к. то что вы спрашиваете, не относится к C# или .NET. Это фичи git/svn или Студии.

Comment: Про SVN не знаю, а в git – можно. Рассказать?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, да, лишним не будет.

Comment: Насколько я знаю ближайшее что вам подойдёт это свойство externals (https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_ru/tsvn-dug-externals.html), правда не знаю есть ли это в VS или нет.

Answer (score 5):

Обязательно должно быть в Visual Studio? Вот как как это сделать в командной строке ([отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401951/is-it-possible-to-link-svn-repository-files-so-that-a-file-is-actually-a-referen)):

```
svn propset svn:externals 'akismet http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/akismet/trunk' .
```

- akismet - Имя директории или файла для связи репозитория
- http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/akismet/trunk - Путь до репозитория который вы хотите привязать
- . - Путь до директории где вы хотите иметь связь

После запуска необходимо залить и обновить через

```
svn commit
```

and

```
svn update
```